# C# Advice on access to static variable across multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I have one static class with two static variables.

I have one thread that assigns these two static variables with data read from an external app, continuously

```
while (enabled) 
{ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

I have several threads that need read-only access to these static variables, continuously

```
while (enabled) 
{ 
    // do stuff depending on value in static variables 
}
```

I need the data to be up to date and the "several threads" to run asynchronously. I also have conditional code in the "several threads".

Should I lock the object, or would marking it as volatile work?

I need the code to be fast as well.

I haven't worked much with threads, so any advice would be nice.

Comment: Do you rely on value of static variables won't change during you act on them in your "several threads"? Depends on details (though volatile almost certainly won't help), but propably reader-writer lock is your best bet (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: what do you mean by conditional code in the "reader" threads?

Comment: using locks generally slows down the system because the critical section inside the lock block can only be accessed by one thread at a time, and any concurrency will result in other threads queuing up to gain access.

Comment: @Evk - It most likely will change, but I think as long as the "several threads" can act on the data that they first received, it should be good.

Comment: If two variables are independent, and after reading them you dont care if they later change - volatile should be enough. But ensure that is really the case, most often its not. Otherwise as I said it depends on what you do.